# linux drop_cache using "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" not working as expected

Tags: linux, memory, cache, buffer, free

In our production environment we are running drop cache command `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to free the RAM. But also what I found is dropping caches is not a good practice and also it won't help much because when a process require more memory and if that much of memory is not free then OS will clear the cache and allocate memory accordingly.

Also technically value of **available** memory before and after running `drop_caches` command should be same.

But when I ran few tests found that dropping caches really helped me in getting some free RAM

`free -h` - **Before dropping cache**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        4.2G        524M        306M        2.9G        2.8G
Swap:          4.0G        439M        3.6G
```

`free-h` - **After dropping cache**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        3.3G        3.8G        306M        452M        3.8G
Swap:          4.0G        439M        3.6G
```

As we can see **available** memory increased by 1GB, what more interesting is **used** memory almost reduced by 1GB. This is where I'm very much confused, isn't `drop_cache` command should have only cleared `cached memory`? why it is even clearing memory used by some running process(i.e **used** memory)

Can someone please explain

1. how `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` command is working ?
2. how available memory is calculated in free command (breakdown of
   available memory)

---

---

### After edit

One of my questions is still not answered

> Also technically value of available memory before and after running drop_caches command should be same

As we dicussed, **available** memory includes reclaimable slab objects

> Right, since reclaimable slab objects isn’t included in either free, buffers, or cache, that means that it ends up in used.
> The definition of “available” explicitly includes it so it is included there too.

But when I ran `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` - To free reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes)

**Before dropping cache**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        4.2G        397M        331M        3.0G        2.7G
Swap:          4.0G        429M        3.6G
```

**After dropping cache**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        3.3G        3.8G        331M        483M        3.8G
Swap:          4.0G        429M        3.6G
```

As we can see here **available** memory has increased after dropping cache, but since I've used `echo 2`, it only free `reclaimable slab objects`. As **available** memory always includes `reclaimable slab objects` running `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` shouldn't have changed value of **available** memory.

But it is not true in my case.

Comment: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` is working as expected, it’s the calculation for “used” that doesn’t match your expectations; see the linked question for details (and the links in the answer there for details of “available”).

Comment: @StephenKitt does increase in **available** memory after running drop_cache is expected?

Comment: @StephenKitt Also what I still don't understand is, if **used** memory excludes **cached** memory and `drop_caches` clears **cached** memory, how does the value of **used** memory is getting reduced after running `drop_caches`. I'm not able to find the link here 

Comment: You’re not just dropping caches, you’re reclaiming slab objects; that accounts for the increase in free memory.

Comment: @StephenKitt then why dropping cache is not treated as good practice, when it can actually free some RAM? and why it is not much common?

Comment: Because the kernel knows how to free reclaimable slab objects when necessary too. See [the kernel docs on the topic](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#drop-caches): “This file is not a means to control the growth of the various kernel caches (inodes, dentries, pagecache, etc…) These objects are automatically reclaimed by the kernel when memory is needed elsewhere on the system.”

Comment: “Use of this file can cause performance problems. Since it discards cached objects, it may cost a significant amount of I/O and CPU to recreate the dropped objects, especially if they were under heavy use. Because of this, use outside of a testing or debugging environment is not recommended.”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141088/discussion-between-swastik-and-stephen-kitt).